# Simple Java Regex Guidance / Explanation

Tags: java, regex, rtf

I'm working on a project where I need to edit an rtf file, I'm having a lot of trouble with the regex for it and I'm trying to figure out how to understand it better / what I am doing wrong.

The input file is always given in this format:

```
abc123_456
Q   How much room was there between the bike rack and the snow pile?
A   There was about three or four feet.
Q   Was the whole place covered with snow?
A   Most of that place was covered with snow.
```

And I have to edit it so it will be in this format:

```
abc123_456
How much room was there between the bike rack and the snow pile?
There was about three or four feet.
Was the whole place covered with snow?
Most of that place was covered with snow.
```

I would also appreciate some help fixing up the redundant / inelegant areas of my code, but for the moment I'll be happy with producing a working output. My current code is here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.EditorKit;


public class StringEditing {
 String[] linesInDoc;

 private static String readRTF(File file){
  String documentText = "";
  try{
   JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
   p.setContentType("text/rtf");
   EditorKit rtfKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
   rtfKit.read(new FileReader(file), p.getDocument(), 0);
   rtfKit = null; 
   EditorKit txtKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/plain");
   Writer writer = new StringWriter();
   txtKit.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
   documentText = writer.toString();
  }
  catch( FileNotFoundException e )
  {
   System.out.println( "File not found" );
  }
  catch( IOException e )
  {
   System.out.println( "I/O error" );
  }
  catch( BadLocationException e )
  {
  }
  return documentText;
 }
 public static void editDocument(File file){
  String plaintext = readRTF(file);
  System.out.println(plaintext);
  plaintext = fixString(plaintext);
  System.out.println(plaintext);

 }
 private static String fixString(String input){
  String removedPrefix = input.replaceAll("(A|Q) *(.+)\r", "$2\r");
  return removedPrefix;
 }
}
```

The current output is this:

```
fqt225_106
    How much room was there between the bike rack and the snow pile?
    There was about three or four feet.
    Was the whole place covered with snow?
    Most of that place was covered with snow.
```

In plain english, the problem is to remove the first letter and following whitespace of all lines except the first line. My own attemps have frequently removed all /s characters which isn't good because of the newline character that I need to keep.

Thank you!

[1] 
Current code based on the suggestions of jbd and David Knipe

```
 public static void editDocument(File file){
   String plaintext = readRTF(file);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   System.out.println(plaintext);
   String[] lines = plaintext.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^[QA] *");
    for(String s: lines){
      Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);
      sb.append(match.replaceFirst(""));
      sb.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

 }
```

Small Update, I have fixed my problem by adding .trim() on each line, replacing my other sb.append statement with:

```
sb.append(match.replaceFirst("").trim());
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you skip the first line you don't need a regex for that line then use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[Q|A][ ]*");

String s = "Q   How much room was there between the bike rack and the snow pile?";

Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);

System.out.println(match.replaceFirst(""));
```

Comment: Character classes don't need `|`, and a single character doesn't need a character class; so `"[QA] *"` should be equivalent. Since `|` is not a special character in character classes, your `|` matches a literal `|`, so if the string started with `|` you'd get a match. It's also awkward that you're only doing one replace at a time when regexes are capable of so much more than this. But if you do `replaceAll` as OP did, it will misbehave, eg `Q   Are bicycles snowproof?` will match twice and remove the `A` too. You may be able to get round this using `"^[QA] *"`.

Comment: Oh, and if you do use `^` to anchor at the start of each line, then you need to use multiline, otherwise it will only try to match from the start of the whole string. That's `Pattern.compile("^[QA] *", Pattern.MULTILINE);` if you're doing it jbd's way, or alternatively use `"(?m)^[QA] *"`.

Comment: Hi, thank you both for the help, however my initial problem of extra whitespace at the beginning of each line remains... I realize now I did not make it clear in my question, but I need to remove this whitespace... The current output is the same as it was initially. I will include my current code in an edit marked [1].